# MySQL to MSSQL Replication

Tags: mysql, sql-server, replication, database-replication

**Source:** MySQL hosted on Windows OS. (I am unaware of the versions of both)

**Destination:** MSSQL 2012 hosted on Windows 2012

**Requirement:** Scheduled migration (once a day at least) of data from Source to destination for ~300 tables

**System:** This is for a Finance company wherein the application DB is MYSQL but the DWH is in MSSQL

I checked online and found these options:

1. Using Oracle Goldengate tool as it supports replication between MySQL to MSSQL, but this will involve licensing of Goldengate and hence very slim chances of this getting approved.
2. SSIS Packages built and running on the destination MSSQL which Pull data on a scheduled time from the MySQL, but at source not every table has a date-time stamp column and hence not sure how the SSIS packages will identify the data which was Inserted/Updated after the last run.

What are the other feasible options I should try? 
Are there any other solutions available in the market which support MYSQL TO MSSQL replication?

Answer (score 1):

- Option 3. Create a linked server using MySql ODBC driver, then use SQL to pull in data.
- Option 4. Expose mySQL database as a REST service ([link](http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/))  Use SSIS JSON task ([link](https://zappysys.com/blog/call-rest-api-using-ssis-web-service-task/)) to pull in data.

Comment: * Option 4: Write your own tool to replicate the data based on triggers